# Code for swapping integers works in C++ but not C

Tags: c++, c, pass-by-reference, swap

I have this function that swaps integers passed by reference, it works fine in C++ but it does not work in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int & x, int & y) 
{ 
    int z = x; 
    x = y; 
    y = z; 
}

int main() 
{
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    swap(a, b);
    printf("a is now %d\n", a);
    printf("b is now %d\n", b);
}
```

Why doesn't it work in C?

Comment: C does not support pass-by-reference, because C does not have references.

Comment: Because it is not C code, and does not compile. C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: The isn't that the code doesn't work in C. It doesn't even **compile** in C. Because it's not legal C.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. C++ supports references. `int & x, int & y` in the `swap` parameter list are references. They refer to another object in memory. Actions taken on a reference actually take place on the object they are referring to. C does not have references. Similar C code would use pointers instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are two different languages, you can't expect that something that works in one can work in the other, passing by reference is not possible in C.

You can, however, pass by pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* const x, int* const y)  
{ 
    int z = *x; 
    *x = *y; 
    *y = z; 
}  

int main() 
{
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    swap(&a, &b);
    printf("a is now %d\n", a);
    printf("b is now %d\n", b);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

C and C++ have some overlap, but they are two different languages. C has no references.

Even the claim that C++ is a superset of C is outdated. C has evolved since C++ started as "C with classes" and not all features added to C are also incorporated into C++. Hence it should not be too surprising that what works in one does not necessarily work in the other.

Comment: Even if C++ *were* a true superset of C this wouldn’t imply that the code should work: the whole point of a superset is that it contains elements (here: references) not contained in the subset.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I know and I think what I wrote does not imply that. I just wrote it for the sake of completeness

Comment: @KonradRudolp rephrased it to make it less misunderstandable

Answer (score 3):

This line declares 2 parameters as [references](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/611-references/):

```
void swap(int & x, int & y)
```

The C language does not have references.

If you attempt to compile this with a C compiler, you should get:

```
error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
```

[IDEOne link](https://ideone.com/7WjuiW)

Answer (score 2):

C does not have references but you can use pointers or make a macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define swap(X,Y) do {int Z=X; X=Y; Y=Z;} while(0)

int main() 
{
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    swap(a, b);
    printf("a is now %d\n", a);
    printf("b is now %d\n", b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AS in c language to be able to change the actual value for a certain variable you should call it by reference so in this code to be able to change (swape) between variables you should use method of call by address ( here when you finish swape function the copied variables will be removed from the memory and actual variables will stay with the same values )

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* x, int* y) 
{ 

    *x=*x^ *y;
     *y=*x ^ *y;
     *x=*x ^ *y;        
}  
int main() 
{
    int a =0, b = 1;
    swap(&a,&b);
    printf("a is now %d\n", a);
    printf("b is now %d\n", b);
}
```

note: swap(a,b); is wrong in c language you should pass these variables by address to be able to swape their values as swape function return void

another solution

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* x, int*  y)  
{   int z = *x ;
     *x = *y ;
      *y=z;
}  

int main() 
{
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    swap(&a, &b);
    printf("a is now %d\n", a);
    printf("b is now %d\n", b);
}
```

Comment: That xor swap is [not a great idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice), it's not faster and it doesn't save memory.

Comment: xor save memory more than second method as there isn't need to create the third variables (int z) which will book 4 byte in the memory

Comment: Not true, there is no third variable in memory. It's all done in registers and here's [compiled assembly that shows this](https://godbolt.org/z/lwK90m). Good compilers and modern CPUs have made xor swap pointless for years.

Comment: As there is a trade of between two method which i mentioned them in my solution with respect to xor method valid only with unsigned variables and with respect to second method it is bad for memory

Comment: Again, the temporary swap **isn't bad for memory**. Your xor swap doesn't use unsigned variables so you're saying it isn't valid? The xor swap also has an aliasing bug, if the same address is passed for both parameters the values are zeroed out.