# Swap number bug

Tags: c

I wrote a simple program that accepts 2 number to be swap in `swapNum` function however, it returns some numbers I don't understand. Can someone explain how this happened and suggests better.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int swapNum(int num1, int num2){
    int tempNumber;
    tempNumber = num1;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = tempNumber;
    return num1;
    return num2;
}
int main(){
    int firstNum, secondNum;
    printf("Enter the first number:");
    scanf("%i", &firstNum);
    printf("Enter the second number:");
    scanf("%i", &secondNum);
    printf("Swapped value: first number: %i, second number: %i", swapNum(firstNum,secondNum));
    return 0;
}
```

[Here is the image of the result. The bug is at the last line at second number.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwDvD.png)

Comment: `return num2` is never reached. You can't return 2 values like that – that's why `printf()` ends up printing garbage.

Comment: `return num1;
return num2;` The second return statement is unreachable.

Comment: You can't have two reurn statements, after the first return, the rest of the code is not executed, I'd suggest passing the arguments as pointers and swap them. Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60937637/6865932

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you can only have one return statement from a function and thus only return on parameter (although it can be a structure).

In this instance I would pass the integer values into the function by using integer pointers and passing their address e.g.:

```
int swapNum(int *num1, int *num2);
int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    printf("a=%d   b=%d\n",a,b);
    
    swapNum(&a, &b);
    printf("a=%d   b=%d\n",a,b);

    return 0;
}

int swapNum(int *num1, int *num2)
{
    int tempNumber;
    tempNumber = *num1;
    *num1 = *num2;
    *num2 = tempNumber;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
a=2   b=3
a=3   b=2
```

Comment: No need to return a value from `swapNum` function. You can declare it as`void swapNum(int *num1, int *num2)`; and remove `return 0;` from the function.

Comment: True, I was just lazy in altering the OP code.

Comment: Actually your `swapNum` should be a void function, because returning anything from it is pointless